kdb q Get last business day usind .z.d
What would be the best way to get the last business day?
I know .z.d - x gets the previous day from x days ago but doesn't necessarily exclude weekends and holidays. Does anyone know if there is a built-in function already?

To get last business day you need to have a holiday calendar. You can get last weekday using
q)prevwday:{x-1^(1 2!2 3)mod[x;7]};
q)prevwday .z.d
2024.04.09

but as I eluded to above, it won't skip holidays unless you have calendar data.
Use scan/over to get a sequence of prev 5 weekdays or the 5th weekday back
q)prevwday\[5;.z.d]
2024.04.10 2024.04.09 2024.04.08 2024.04.05 2024.04.04 2024.04.03
q)
q)prevwday/[5;.z.d]
2024.04.03

